# eigen value solver based on BOOST UBLAS

Tags: boost, ublas

These days I am starting learning BOOST UBLAS and BOOST MATH for my tasks.

I was bit surprised to find that there is no eigenvalue/vector solver in it.

Since I would like to stick with Boost libs and their matrix classes, do you know about any library built on top of boost ublas capables to find eigenvalues and other stuff that might extend it or that are capable (at least) to accept boost matrix as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost ublas does not implement the gory details of numeric algorithms, it just provides a nice template interface. Access to matrix libs is provided through boost bindings, e.g. [LaPack Bindings](http://mathema.tician.de/node/391).

Answer (score 1):

I used MKL for that problem. Of course it isn't connected with uBLAS